# Restricting personal accounts user login

Tags: authentication, authorization

I have to build a portal for my institute which will act as a job portal for the institute. Companies should be able to post their job/intern openings on the portal. For that to happen, one prime condition is that HRs should login only with their work profiles and thus their personal accounts(gmail,etc.) should be restricted. I have seen some similar questions where we had to whitelist a particular domain and restrict all others but this might not be feasible in this case, as whitelisting all the work domains doesn't seem practical. Is there a built-in solution for this?
My Tech Stack is:
NextJS for the frontend.
For the backend part, I am thinking of either NodeJS+mongoDB OR Sanity.io depending on a more feasible solution for the above problem statement...

Answer (score -1):

Restrict yahoo/gmail and only allow their company's email or school's email (.edu). You can also have a dropdown of whitelisted school's email or company.

School or companies who wish to join your platform will have to be manually added once. Basically whitelisted list can perform registration in the future.